# Creating key value pairs (reduced by key) from a string of data separated by spaces in Apache Spark with Java

Tags: apache-spark

I am just starting with Apache Spark. I have a data set that looks like the following:

```
A1: Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4
A2: X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
A3: L1 L2
A4: Z1 X4 L2
```

I want the RDD to look like the following:
(A1, [Z1,Z2,Z3,Z4]) where A1 is the key and [Z1,Z2,Z3,Z4] are iterable string values. 
I am able to separate the key and the values on colon, but I don't know how to proceed further. Here is part of my code.

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<String>> links = lines.mapToPair(s -> {
            String[] parts = COLONS.split(s);
            String[] outGoingLinks = SPACES.split(parts[1]);
            return new Tuple2<>(parts[0], parts[1]);
        }).distinct().groupByKey().cache();
```

line looks like A1: Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4

parts[0] has my keys, and parts[1] has all the values for a key separated by spaces: Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4

Comment: you should do "explode" first, to generate pairs, for example A1:Z1, A1:Z2, A1:Z3, A1:Z4, then pick distincts, then group by key

Comment: if you do it current way, then in case if for example A1 occurs twice and has values A1:Z1 Z2 Z3 and A1:Z2 Z3 Z4 then your function would return A1: ["Z1 Z2 Z3", "Z2 Z3 Z4"], in other words, iterable values are "Z1 Z2 Z3" and "Z2 Z3 Z4", instead of what you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "explode" mentioned in my comment above is `flatMap` which produces more than one output rows from a single input row.
You may use the following fragment (this could be implemented by `flatMapToPair` alone without involving `mapToPair` but I did it two-step in order to be clear for you what's actually going on):

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<String>> links = 

lines.flatMap(s -> {

List<String> pairs = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] parts = COLONS.split(s);
String[] outGoingLinks = SPACES.split(parts[1]);
for(int i=0; i < outGoingLinks.length; i++) 
        pairs.add(parts[0] + " " + outGoingLinks[i]);
return pairs.iterator();

}).mapToPair(s -> {

String[] parts = SPACES.split(s);
return new Tuple2<String, String>(parts[0], parts[1]);

}).distinct().groupByKey().cache();
```